# Default route is matched instead specific route

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, routes, zend-route

```
<routes>
    <www type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname">
        <route>www.domain.com</route>
        <chains>
            <index type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
                <route></route>
                <defaults module="default" controller="index" action="index" />
            </index>
            <community>
                <route>community</route>
                <defaults module="community" />
                <chains>
                    <index type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
                        <route>:action/*</route>
                        <defaults controller="index" action="index" />
                    </index>
                    <member type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex">
                        <route>member/profile-(\d+)-(.+)</route>
                        <reverse>member/profile-%d-%s</reverse>
                        <map>
                            <id>1</id>
                            <nom>2</nom>
                        </map>
                        <defaults action="viewmember" />
                    </member>
                </chains>
            </community>
        </chains>
    </www>
```

As you can see, I use a route  with :action/* in to cover the homepages and the basics actions on index controller.

domain.com/community/random_action => works good.

domain.com/community/ doesn't work. The whole homepage is displayed.
I checked, and the default route is matched.

I tried assemble() on route "www-community-index" and it gives well www.domain.com/community

I don't see from where comes the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should check is if you deleted the default route.
The second one is....remember that the routes are checked in reverse order. This means that the most specific should be the first and the default the last one.